# Nest.js is unable to resolve Mongoose model dependency in unit test

Tags: node.js, nestjs

When writing a unit test for a controller, Nest is unable to resolve my Mongoose model dependency:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make
>   sure that the argument USER_MODEL at index [0] is available in the
>   _RootTestModule context.
>
> ```
> Potential solutions:
> - If USER_MODEL is a provider, is it part of the current _RootTestModule?
> - If USER_MODEL is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within _RootTestModule?
>   @Module({
>     imports: [ /* the Module containing USER_MODEL */ ]
>   })
> ```

My model is injected via my service constructor in the users.service.ts:

```typescript
import { IUserModel } from './interfaces';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { USER_MODEL } from './constants/users.constants';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  constructor (
    @Inject(USER_MODEL)
    private readonly userModel: Model<IUserModel>,
  ) {}

  ...
}
```

and my test is defined as:

```typescript
const mockUserModel = {};

describe('Users Controller', () => {
  let usersController: UsersController;
  let usersService: UsersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: getModelToken(USER_MODEL),
          useValue: mockUserModel,
        },
        UsersService,
      ],
    }).compile();

    usersController = module.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
    usersService = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  it('should define user controller and service', () => {
    expect(usersController).toBeDefined();
    expect(usersService).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

All of these classes are defined in the same module. I'm not quite sure what Nest is looking for. I'm following the guide at: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing and have looked through several older Github issues as well.

I've also tried creating a custom class provider as defined here: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers to supply the typed Mongoose Model, but that returned the same error.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `@Inject(USER_MODEL)` then you need to use `provide: USER_MODEL` in your test. The `getModelToken` utility method is necessary if you use `@InjectModel()` instead of the raw `@Inject()`.

Comment: Thanks, but how am I supposed to create the testing module? Do you have any example code or documentation?

Comment: I have [an entire repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) dedicated to test examples. Feel free to check them out. Your set up is mostly right, just providing the wrong `mock token` for your model.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for the great documentation!

Comment: Looking through the repo, I'm not seeing anything in regards to Passport and testing controllers with AuthGuards. Searches aren't coming up with a lot of examples. In the past I've opted for E2E tests and setting up a separate database for testing. If you have an alternative approach, I'd appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: I'd say using docker-compose for e2e testing is something important to work with. It's something I'm slowly working on in regards to the testing repository, along with showing an e2e of passport testing.

Comment: So for now, would you suggest skipping unit tests on controllers protected with AuthGuards in favor of e2e tests for those routes?

Comment: I think unit tests on the controller are fine to have, the controller should basically just return whatever the service it calls does. You can also unit test your guards to make sure that logic works as expected. If you are looking to test that the guards work in combination with the controller though, that has to be done with e2e tests

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I can always construct a fake user object to assign to the request and mock the request with node-mocks-http to pass into those functions. Thanks for the tips!